# Awk: concatenating split field element from one file to another based on common field

Tags: awk

I have two tab-delimited files, `f1` and `f2`, that look like this:

`f1:`

```
id1    r1
id2    r2
id3    r3
...
idN    rN
```

`f2:`

```
f1    g1    x1;id1
f2    g2    x2;id2
f4    g4    x2;id4
...
fM    gM    xm;idM
```

where `N` and `M` may be different. I'm looking to create an associative array of `f1` and concatenate the second column of `f1` to the end of `f2` such that the output is:

```
f1    g1    x1;id1=r1
f2    g2    x2;id2=r2
...
```

As a test, I've run this:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{id[$1]=$1; r[$1]=$2; next} {split($3,a,";"); if (a[2] in id) {print "found"} else {print "not found"}}' f1 f2`

which gives output:

```
 found
 found
 not found
 ...
```

However, running the following command:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{id[$1]=$1; r[$1]=$2; next} {split($3,a,";"); if (a[2] in id) {$3=$3"="r[$1]; print} else {print "not found"}}' f1 f2`

gives the output:

```
f1      g1      x1;id1=
f2      g2      x2;id2=
not found
...
```

My question is: how do I access the value associated with the key such that I can append it to the 3rd column of `f2`?

Comment: Please get rid of all the `...`s, they just clutter up your examples and make it so we can't copy/paste them to test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 1):

`join` is the tool for joining files, especially if they are already sorted by the key.

```
$ join -14 <(sed 's/;/; /' file2) file1 | 
   awk '{print $2,$3,$4$1 "=" $5}' 

f1 g1 x1;id1=r1
f2 g2 x2;id2=r2
```

however, your output format is not standard, so need `awk` for that purpose. I guess in that case the whole script can be done in `awk` as well.